# adding simple if statement sends email twice

Tags: php, email

I have a PHP email script. It functions fine, but I wanted to add a very simple verification.
When I add the following code, the email sends twice. Without this code, the email will only send once like it is supposed to.

It seems like it's reading the `@mail...` function twice, even though it is wrapped in an if statement. Does anyone know why it's sending twice?

**PHP**   --

```
 <? 
 if(@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)) {
 echo "
 <h1>Success</h1>
 <hr>
 <p>Thank you for your submission. <br>Your Wishlist has been sent to one of our sales reps. We'll respond to you shortly.</p>";
 }
 else { echo 
 "
 <p>Your message was unable to be sent.<br>Please try again.</p>";
 }
 ;?>
```

Comment: That is only going to call mail() once, show the code AROUND this snippet. You'll probably find the if() is being executed twice.

Comment: so this if() actually sends the email out? I thought it was only saying 'if @mail was executed, then do this... If it wasn't do this...

Comment: Nope, any function you put inside of an if clause is actually executed.

Comment: no, it's actually sending another mail. so if you have `mail(...); if (mail(...))` then yes,  you're calling mail twice, sending two mails.

Comment: The `@` in front of mail only suppresses the errors, it doesn't stop the function from doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Ok, I was calling @mail(.......) before this. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results is as expected. You state

> Without this code, the email will only send once like it is supposed to.

So you are calling mail or some other email method before (could be PHP or not). Then you call it again in the if clause.

--> You should get 2 emails.

Comment: yep, I wasn't aware
`if(@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)) {`
would send the email out again. I thought it was just checking if it had been performed. Yay, php.